# PHP Sitemap - error on line 31 at column 2: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sitemap

so I am wondering why this error is showing up. Ive see this work before but all I did was modify the query a bit. For some reason when I get rid of the php loop it works only with the url and loc tags with php inside them. Some help would be great! There error is on line 31 which is right before the php query and loop start.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

include 'core/init.php';?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/1.0">
<url>
    <loc><?php echo $settings['url']; ?></loc>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo $settings['url'] . 'login'; ?></loc>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo $settings['url']. 'register'; ?></loc>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo $settings['url'] . 'sponsored'; ?></loc>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo $settings['url']. 'premium'; ?></loc>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo $settings['url']. 'contact'; ?></loc>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo $settings['url']. 'about'; ?></loc>
</url>

<?php
$result = $database->query("SELECT DISTINCT `slug` FROM `categories`");
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
?>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo $settings['url']  . 'category/' . $row['slug'] . '/'; ?></loc>
</url>
<?php } ?>

</urlset>
```

Thanks!

Comment: > `, FROM` you need to get rid of that comma. That alone should have thrown an error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I just removed that and still the error is showing at line 33 which is the last </url> before the php begins again for the loop and query

Comment: *Hm....* Just a hunch. Try removing all of the `?>` for each of the `<loc><?php echo $settings['url'] . 'X'; ?></loc>` and for `$row['slug'] . '/'; ?></loc>`. XML can play some pretty nasty tricks at times and the manual on php.net, suggests to not use closing php tags when using XML. If that doesn't work, see if php's error reporting picks anything up and try to `var_dump()` stuff.

Comment: To add, if that throws an error, then you might have to keep the closing tag for `$row['slug'] . '/'; ?></loc>`.

Comment: I guess I should probably delete my above comment then *lol*

Comment: lol yeah simple fix i guess

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had some errors in my echo statement. I had to use " instead of ' where it says category/ and just /